# Make Images Fit and Resize properly

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Been trying to fix this myself for awhile and a bit stuck. I can't make these images display properly - Keeping there position in mobile and desktop view.

Probably easy to solve for most people. I am trying to re-make this website, http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/ , as a lesson in web page design .

here's my code

```
/**
 * Created by Hewlbern on 21-Jan-17.
 */
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        var background = {
            backgroundSize : 'cover'
        };
        var heroStyle = {
            width:'auto',
            overflow : 'hidden',
        };
        var ontop = {
            position: 'relative',
            display: 'block',
            margin: 'auto',
            width: '50%',
            bottom: '30%',
            left: '0',
            right: '0',
        };
        return (
            <div style={heroStyle}>
                <Image
                    style={background} responsive
                    src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Home-Background.jpg">
                </Image>
                    <Image
                        style={ontop} responsive
                        src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Digital-Media.png">
                    </Image>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to make a https://jsfiddle.net/ example to help us please. Cheers bro

Comment: Sure! A bit new to this so give me a bit to get one up - Whenever I try to use JSfiddle with react it doesn't work D:

Comment: Yeah well you have to add the libraries ;) Search for "jsfiddle react bootstrap" in google and see how people do ;)

Comment: Thanks Kiwad - Give me 5 minutes!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Trollborn/x70ovn5q/4/#&togetherjs=I742aliQbi

Comment: I can't get it to display in jsfiddle and I don't really know why eugh.

Comment: React doesn't have anything to do with this. Make an example that is about the CSS only.

Comment: Good idea man - Give me 10 mins and i'll edit the post